# Login loop after upgrading to Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: upgrade, login, 23.04

I upgraded from the LTS version to 22.10 which was fine and all, but after I upgraded to 23.04 my laptop got stuck in a login loop after logging in. Things I tried:

- I tried to find the xauthority, which wasn't there
- The permissions of the tmp folder were okay
- I still have enough space in my home folder, around 70% is taken
- I tried creating a test user to login which also got stuck in a login loop
- I tried logging in through cinnamon and a view others through the settings button in the bottom right which loaded even slower

My laptop has a dual boot with windows and the model is Lenovo ThinkPad P15v Gen 2

**UPDATE:** I installed nvidia-smi for driver version 525 and I installed the nvidia driver version 525 and just now I was able to login again. After I login though the screen goes black for a moment, this also happens when suspending, like whenever logging in and logging out happens.

Comment: Does your user account use a nonstandard shell like _zsh_ that might not be installed, or not listed in `/etc/shells`?

Comment: @HuHa No I don't, I did switch my standard terminal to the new gnome console, but I don't think that's what you mean by shell